# Stub Method error in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I study api tutorial on RoR(Ruby-2.1, Rails 4.x) with [this book](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_five).

It is an excellent book to follow, but I got this issue in rspec test in **Chapter 5**. (Please see **Listing 5.9** in that chapter.)

```
Failure/Error: authentication.stub<:request>.and_return<request>
#<Authentication:0x000000075fe220> does not implement: request
```

Source code:

```
class Authentication
  include Authenticable
end

describe Authenticable do
  let(:authentication) { Authentication.new }

  describe "#current_user" do
    before do
      @customer = FactoryGirl.create :customer
      request.headers["Authorization"] = @customer.auth_token
      authentication.stub(:request).and_return(request)
    end
    it "returns the user from the authorization header" do
      expect(authentication.current_user.auth_token).to eql @customer.auth_token
    end
  end
end
```

How can fix this issue?

Comment: i'd say it's a bug in the books code.

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong with its code?

Comment: the exception says it all. authentication does not have a method request, that's why you can't stub it.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to use rspec 3, maybe you can replace the code with this:

spec/controllers/concerns/authenticable_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

class Authentication
  include Authenticable
end

describe Authenticable, :type => :controller do
  let(:authentication) { Authentication.new }

  describe "#current_user" do
    before do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      request.headers["Authorization"] = @user.auth_token
      allow(authentication).to receive(:request).and_return(request)
    end

    it "returns the user from the authorization header" do
      expect(authentication.current_user.auth_token).to eql @user.auth_token
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/concerns/authenticable.rb

```
module Authenticable
  # Devise methods overwrites
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers['Authorization'])
  end

  def request
    request
  end
end
```

pdt: Exist a bug with rspec stub controller helper method. more references https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1076

Comment: Hi Nelson, thanks for your reply! I've been trying to handle this for 2 hours.
I didn't even change the 'spec' file, just added the request method to authenticable.rb file. But I wonder how did it solve the problem, would you please explain briefly?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nelson, thanks for the proposed answer.  Adding the request override fixed the problem for running the authenticable_spec.rb but now I have a lot of other specs failing with the error: Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace - SystemStackError: stack level too deep.  Any insight into why that might be happening?

Comment: This caused the ```stack level too deep``` error too. I think the problem is the request is calling request which is calling request....

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the book, which version of RSpec are you using?, probably you will have to set it to 2.14 like so:

```
group :test do
 gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14"
end
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Is there no way to get this to work with RSpec 3.1?  What is it about RSpec 3.1 that make this not work?  Is there another implementation that would be a little more stable for this Authenticable module?

Answer (score 0):

I would try completing the project with "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14" as suggested.

Once you have finished the tutorial you can then make use of transpec - a gem that will upgrade your tests to be compatible with rspec3.

https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec

Install the gem and upgrade your project > gemfile to "rspec-rails", "~> 3.1.0" and run transpec on the project.

This should update all your tests.

I think this is what your test should look like using rspec 3

```
describe "#current_user" do
    before do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      request.headers["Authorization"] = @user.auth_token
      allow(authentication).to receive(:request).and_return(request)
    end
    it "returns the user from the authorization header" do
      expect(authentication.current_user.auth_token).to eql @user.auth_token
    end
end
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply complete the `Authentication` class in the spec this way:

```
class Authentication
  include Authenticable
  attr_accessor :request, :response
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found by using this github [issue#4](https://github.com/kurenn/market_place_api/issues/4)  I was able to solve this by simply changing:

```
class Authentication
```

in the `authenticable_spec.rb` file to:

```
class Authentication  < ActionController::Base
```

This means that `Authentication` class inherits the `ActionController::Base` request method.